# How to split following string?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i am getting cookie value as parameter .I need to split the cookie value(name,value).

```
string Cookie ="secureToken_sdfsdfbsadbfsdhbh = Tdne68JhO5baix2Ey_K0ICV1HAAFvUP5BA==";
string[] cookieData = Cookie.Split('=')
```

It's even taking the last equal character also.I need following output.

```
cookie[0]=secureToken_sdfsdfbsadbfsdhbh
cookie[1]= Tdne68JhO5baix2Ey_K0ICV1HAAFvUP5BA==
```

It should consider only the first equal character.after that it shouldn't spilt the string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
Cookie.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2)
```

it will limit your split to 2 strings

Answer (score 1):

```
string Cookie ="secureToken_sdfsdfbsadbfsdhbh = Tdne68JhO5baix2Ey_K0ICV1HAAFvUP5BA==";
string[] cookieData = Cookie.Split(new string[] {" = "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (var item in cookieData)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output will be;

```
secureToken_sdfsdfbsadbfsdhbh
Tdne68JhO5baix2Ey_K0ICV1HAAFvUP5BA==
```

Here a <kbd>[`Demonstration`](http://ideone.com/i0C5d7)</kbd>.

**EDIT**: Since you only want 2 split part, limiting will be better as a solution explained in [*wudzik answers*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19565632/447156).

Comment: I think using string.Split with count parameter is a bit cleaner solution, but this is a good answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string str= "secureToken_sdfsdfbsadbfsdhbh = Tdne68JhO5baix2Ey_K0ICV1HAAFvUP5BA==";
string[] separator = { " = " };
string[] strarr = str.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (string s in strarr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: same solution as Soner's, different syntax, new answer should add something